# Combine prefixAndTail(1) with Sink.lazySink for SubFlow created by .splitAfter

Tags: akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I am currently developing an akka-stream/alpakka application that has the following general logic

1. Given a `Flow`, split it into a `SubFlow` using the `splitAfter` method.
2. For each of the `SubFlow`'s in point 1, use `prefixAndTail(1)` to create a key based on the first element of that `Subflow`
3. Attach each `Subflow` to a `Sink` that is given that key *as a parameter*.

So assuming we have a function defined as following which gives us a `Sink`

```scala
def mySink(key: String): Sink[ByteString, Future[Done]]
```

Essentially what I want to do is something like this

```scala
val source = ???
val subFlows = source.splitAfter(...)
val logic = subflows.prefixAndTail(1).flatMapConcat { case (head, rest) =>
  val computedFlow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString]  = ???
  computedFlow
}
val finished = logic.prefixAndTail(1).to(
  Sink.lazySink { (head) => 
    val key = computeKey(head)
    mySink(key)
  }
)
```

This code evidently doesn't compile since `Sink.lazySink`'s  thunk takes 0 parameters. I tried other variations however I haven't gotten anywhere. In the documentation for `Sink.lazySink` it says that you can combine it with `prefixAndTail(1)` to get the first element out of the flow presumably so you can use the first element as an input to the final `Sink` which in my case is `mySink(key)` (like with the combination of `prefixAndTail(1).flatMapConcat` on a `Flow`). The problem is that the `.to` command doesn't accept parameters (only a raw `Sink`) so you end up with the following problem

```scala
val finished = logic.prefixAndTail(1).to(
  Sink.lazySink { () => 
    // How do I get the first element out of the sink so I can compute
    // the key?
    val key = computeKey(???)
    mySink(key)
  }
)
```

I tried computing the key in the `logic` `Flow` however then you have to compose `Sink`'s of two different types (one which is the key, computed from the head of the subflow and the other which is the original `Sink` that accepts a `ByteStream`) which doesn't really work

```scala
val logic = subflows.prefixAndTail(1).flatMapConcat { case (head, rest) =>
  ...
  val computedFlow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString] = ???
  val key = computeKey(head)
  computedFlow.map(something => (something, key) )
}
val finished = logic.to(
  Sink.lazySink { () => 
    // Here I have to return a Sink[ByteString, String] but 
    // mySink only returns returns Sink[ByteString].
    // I essentially need to do something along the lines of Sink[String].flatMap(key => mySink(key))
    // but this doesn't work because Sink's don't have an output
  }
)
```

So hence I am kind of stuck. Since I am working with a `SubFlow` I have a limited set of methods and I can't seem to find a way to pass the key (which you compute with the first element from each `SubFlow`) to pass as a parameter to `mySink(key: String)`

`Sink.lazyInit` appears to close to what I want, I managed to get the following to compile

```scala
val logic = subflows.prefixAndTail(1).flatMapConcat { case (head, rest) =>
  ...
  val computedFlow(head, rest): Flow[ByteString, ByteString] = ???
  val key = computeKey(head)
  computedFlow.map(something => (something, key) )
}
val finished = logic.to(
  Sink.lazyInit( { case (_, key} =>
    Future.successful(
      mySink(key).contramap[(ByteString, String)] { case (content, _) => content }
    )
  ), ???)
)
```

Although the problem is that `Sink.lazyInit` is deprecated and so I would prefer to use the `prefixAndTail(1).to(Sink.lazySink)` combination (as stated in the depreciation message). Also I am unsure as to what the point of requiring a `Future` is (and whether `Future.successful` is appropriate or should I use standard `Future.apply` that requires an `ExecutionContext`).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this compiles in my mind

```scala
def logic: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = ???

val finished = logic.prefixAndTail(1).to {
  val donePromise = Promise[Done]()
  Sink.foreach {
    case (prefix, tail) =>
      prefix.headOption match {
        case None => donePromise.success(Done)
        case Some(head) =>
          donePromise.completeWith(tail.runWith(mySink(head)))
      }
  }.mapMaterializedValue(_ => donePromise.future)
}
```

`prefixAndTail` emits only one element (the tuple of `prefix` and `tail`), so we can use `Sink.foreach` to wait until that emission to attach `mySink` to `tail` and run it.  We also effectively replace the materialized value of the `Sink.foreach` with the materialized value of `mySink`.

```scala
val finished = logic.to {
  Sink.fromMaterializer { (mat, _) =>
    // TODO: plumb stream attributes through
    val sinkPromise = Promise[Sink[ByteString, Future[Done]]]()
    Flow[ByteString].prefixAndTail(1)
      .wireTap {
        case (prefix, tail) =>
          prefix.headOption match {
            case None => sinkPromise.success(Sink.ignore) // or fail with an exception signalling nothing materialized
            case Some(head) => sinkPromise.success(mySink(head))
          }
      }
      .flatMapConcat(_._2)
      .toMat(Sink.lazyFutureSink(() => sinkPromise.future))(Keep.right)
  }
}
```

`Sink.fromMaterializer` seems the only way to setup a per-materialization channel (the promise/future combination) for getting a sink built from a stream element into `lazyFutureSink`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however this is basically the implementation of `Sink.lazyInit`, i.e. https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/3a3e643e074d2e57e320b8efb38bb7fba440e4b3/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Sink.scala#L625-L638

So this isn't any better than using `Sink.lazyInit`

Comment: Came up with an alternative approach which is the only thing I can think of that uses `prefixAndTail` with `lazyFutureSink`... I've posted a question in the Akka Gitter channel, because it's a bit of a mystery how to do this without something crazy like this.

Comment: The PR discussions around steering everyone to `prefixAndTail` with `lazyFutureSync` do call the technique out as being obscure.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide the alternative solution that uses `prefixAndTail` + `lazyFutureSync`, I am also curious what it is. Definitely agree with you that the solution to this problem appears to be obscure in general.

Comment: I must have forgotten to hit save on the edit where I added it....

Comment: It should be there now, barring some eventual consistency gremlins in SO